# How to know when async for loop is done?

Tags: javascript, loops, promise

I have a for loop that kicks off hundreds of async functions. Once all functions are done I need to run one last function but I can't seem to wrap my head around it knowing when all functions are complete.

I've tried promises but as soon as any of the functions in the loop resolve then my promise function completes.

```
for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i ++){
// these can take up to two seconds and have hundreds in the array
asyncFunction(someArray[i];
}
```

How can I tell once every function has completed?

Comment: You likely want to look into "Promises".

Comment: You are looking for `Promise.all`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: You should collect an array of promises, one for every call to the async function in your loop and then after pass that array of promises to the Promise.all method Felix King linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## An increment

You can add a callback which increments:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    asycFunction(someArray[i]);
    asycFunction.done = function () {
        if (i == someArray.length - 1) {
            // Done with all stuff
        }
    };
}
```

---

## A recursive approach

This type of approach is more liked by some developers but (might) take longer to execute because it waits for one to finish, to run another.

```
var limit = someArray.length, i = 0;

function do(i) {
    asyncFunction(someArray[i]);
    asyncFunction.done = function () [
        if (i++ == someArray[i]) {
            // All done!
        } else { do(i); }
    }
}
do(i++);
```

---

## Promises

Promises aren't well supported at the moment but you can use a library. It will add a little bulk to your page for sure though.

---

## A nice solution

```
(function (f,i) {
    do(i++,f)
}(function (f,i) {
    asyncFunction(someArray[i]);
    asyncFunction.done = function () {
        if (i++ === someArray.length - 1) {
            // Done
        } else { f(i) }
    };
}, 0)
```

Comment: I actually tried your first suggestion with increments, the issue I ran into is the for loop starts the async function then doesn't wait and loops again. So when the if statement equal'd true it just meant that the loop was done starting the async functions not that they were complete.

Comment: @Skej that's exactly what the second solution aims to fix. Try that and hopefully it works

Comment: Recursive approach did it. I had thought of that but it seemed like a duct tape solution, but if it looks stupid and it works, it isn't stupid.

Comment: @Skej I've added a nicer, non-doct-tape solution. It uses anonymous functions which are more reusable without heavy modification

Answer (score 3):

Many libraries have `.all` resolver:

- [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)
- [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#user-content-combination)
- [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#collections)
- and many more - https://promisesaplus.com/implementations

You can use them or learn their source code.

Assuming the code to be the body of function `foo()` :

```
function foo() {
    return Promise.all(someArray.map(function(item) {
        //other stuff here
        return asyncFunction(item, /* other params here */);
    }));
}
```

Or, if there's no other stuff to do, and no other params to pass :

```
function foo() {
    return Promise.all(someArray.map(asyncFunction));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check number of response.

For every response you can increase counter value and if counter value same as someArray.length then you can assume all Async functions are done and can start next step.